# How can I access my MongoDB on my Linode VPS?

Tags: mongodb, vps, linode

I have a nodejs app running on my Linode VPS, with MongoDB installed. I cannot connected to the database on the same VPS as it gives me 'Unauthorised' error.

**SETTING UP THE DB AND USER ON THE VPS**

To set up the database on my MongoDB instance I SSH'd into my VPS and entered into the mongo shell:

```
$ mongo
```

I then switched to the admin database, and tried to view the users of it. The first stranage thing was it wouldnt let me do that:

```
use admin
switched to db admin
show users
```

The error I got was as follows:

```
2020-05-22T12:13:25.362+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: not authorized on admin to execute command { usersInfo: 1.0, lsid: { id: UUID("bbb18683-839f-4c7d-b453-f774cbc94efd") }, $db: "admin" } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.getUsers@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1763:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:859:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:766:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

I carried on, to create a user in the admin database, so that I could then create a user in my app's database to enable me to connect to the app's database:

```
db.createUser({user: "superAdmin",pwd: "admin123",roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]})
```

Which was successfull:

```
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "superAdmin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I then re-loaded the mongod service and logged into the shell with the user I just made:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "superAdmin" -p "admin123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

I then switched to my app's db and made the user as follows:

```
use appDB
switched to db appDB
db.createUser({user: "DBuser",pwd: "DBpassword",roles: ["readWrite"]})
Successfully added user: { "user" : "DBuser", "roles" : [ "readWrite" ] }
```

**ACCESSING THE DB WITH THE CREATED USER FROM THE APP ON SAME LINODE**

Within my node.js app, which is on the same linode VPS I use the following connection URI:

```
'mongodb://DBuser:DBpassword@localhost:27017/appDB'
```

Now when I run the seeds file, whilst SSH'd into the VPS, to populate the database on the VPS I get an unauthorized error:

```
errmsg:
   'not authorized on appDB to execute command { dropDatabase: 1, lsid: { id: UUID("b2c1ffc7-1912-42e3-8f74-ab3726dff3f2") }, $db: "appDB" }',
  code: 13,
  codeName: 'Unauthorized',
```

This error even happens when I try to use my frontend app to create a new record in the database.

I cannot even access my database instance on VPS via Insomnia.

This was all working locally without (the user name and password) in the DB URL.

How do I set my MongoDB instance up correctly to accept connections?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS - I followed this instructions to set up my Linode: https://www.codementor.io/@tomgeraghty/hosting-an-express-server-nodejs-application-with-linode-e1j7wt7mr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave your user **readWrite** role, but that role doesn't allow execution of command **dropDatabase**, only the **dbAdmin** role can do that.
See the available built-in roles here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

Ideally, you'd create yourself a custom role with all the necessary privileges required, and assign that role to your application's user.
More info on user-defined roles here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-user-defined-roles/